Iphone 'hamburger' button doesnt work well. Website made with elementor pro
I made a website using elementor pro. I made a menu with an hamburger button. When I click it on my android phone it opens normal. When I use an iphone with developer tools it works as well.
But a physical iPhone doesn't work well. I have a video to show it.
I cant send the video here so i'll send a screenshot of the problem.
This is the site in question:

https://mindandnoor.com
I tried to copy this in the hamburger button 'custom css' part:
.burger-icon div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Safari-specific */
}

.menu-overlay.open .burger-icon div:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

.menu-overlay.open .burger-icon div:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-overlay.open .burger-icon div:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, -5px);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(5px, -5px);
}

.menu-overlay.open {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    will-change: transform;
}

But it still doesn't work..

Your hamburger menu works ok on my iphone. You say you have a video which illustrates the problem ... can you upload the video somewhere (YouTube?) and then edit this post to include a link to it?

yes bro here is the video: https://youtube.com/shorts/id3peqQN8Bg?feature=share

and yes sorry my friend changed the hamburger menu. If you check now on your iPhone you'll see that it doesnt work.
